# WebClient on Windows Phone 7 outside debug

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

I have a Windows Phone & application that uses WebClient to fetch some data from an Azure service. I am able to deploy  the app from VS and debug it on a device. It seems to be working correctly, contacting the web service and getting responses.

However when I disconnect the device from my PC and try to run the app, on the device on it's own, it keeps failing with "The remote server returned an Error: NotFound". Nothing (that I'm aware of) changes between running the app in debug mode and just running it on its own (the same URL is used, the Azure service is still up, etc). The app has ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability defined in its WMAppManifest.

Am I missing something? Do I need to do something else to enable the app to open an HTTP connection on the phone?

Comment: Does it have cell/WiFi connection?

Comment: Are you sure irs connecting to azure and not some debug service

Comment: While Windows Phone is connected to the computer via USB, it accesses the network via the host computer over the USB connection. You can confirm this by trying to access a webpage while airplane mode is on and the phone is plugged in to the host computer. Make sure you actually have network connectivity after you unplug the phone.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. The issue was indeed with connectivity. It did not occur to me that the phone would be using the PC's network connection when debugging (thanks for pointing that out, Fur!)

Comment: @FurDworetzky You should probably put that as an answer so we can wrap this question up.

Comment: @loyalpenguin Alright, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Windows Phone is connected to the computer via USB, it accesses the network via the host computer over the USB connection.

This can mean that a Windows Phone may have connectivity when plugged into the computer, but loses it when it becomes unplugged. If the connectivity situation changes after being unplugged, then it is always good to check the connection after becoming unplugged.